# Regex designed to accept EIN or SSN formats only accepts EIN

Tags: javascript

I used Regex101.com to build and test the regex pattern.  It works perfectly on that website.  I used that regex in Javascript and it seems to NOT accept the SSN format.  Since I only need regex rarely I'm no expert, so I turn to the experts.

```js
// let term = "30-1234567"; // Valid - EIN format
// let term = "31-1234567"; // Invalid - EIN format
let term = "999-99-9999"; // Valid - SSN format
let re = new RegExp("^(0[1-6]|1[0-6]|2[0-7]|3[02-49]|4[0-8]|5[0-9]|6[02-8]|7[1-7]|8[0-8]|9[0-58-9]-\d{7})|(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$");
if (re.test(term)) {
  alert("Valid");
} else {
  alert("Invalid");
}
```

The hyphen (-) must be entered.  Can anyone see my mistake?

Comment: The left sidebar of regex101.com has a menu of different regexp flavors. Did you select JavaScript for your test?

Comment: Use a regexp literal instead of `new RegExp`. Otherwise you need to escape all the backslashes, e.g. `\\d`.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes, I did select 'ECMAScript (Javascript)'.  I also tested with PCRE2 (PHP >= 7.3).  It works perfectly with both.

Comment: When you write `\d` in a string, it turns into just `d`.

Comment: Only use `new RegExp()` when you need to create the regexp dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar, I used 'new RegExp()' because the Javascript validator I use uses it.  Doubling up the \ did the trick.  Thank your for the help.